# If $x$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, then $(x^{2} + 1)^{2}\geq 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If  $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then:

$x^2+1 \geq \dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}$?

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}\ge$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then $x^2+1\ge1$.

On the other hand, $(x-1)^2\ge0$, so $x^2+1\ge 2x$, so $1\ge\dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}$.

Therefore, $x^2+1\ge\dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: complied with the algebra-*pre*calculus tag

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that $x^{2} + 1 \geq 1$. Thus we have

\begin{align*}
(x^{2} + 1)^{2} \geq x^{2} + 1 \geq 2|x| \geq 2x
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider $f(x)=\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{2(1-3x^2)}{(1+x^2)^3}$, so we have maximum in $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ which is $\leqslant 1$. So $x^2+1 \geqslant \dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}$ for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ - @J. W. Tanner's correction is correct.